# Offline Ascii art editor for Linux

Tags: linux, wysiwyg, ascii, flowchart

I use `Ubuntu 16.04` and do not look for something like [Graph_Easy](https://github.com/ironcamel/Graph-Easy) which parses input, instead I look for some offline, free, [WYSIWYG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) software that does tasks like what [asciiflow](http://asciiflow.com/) does. For example these features are necessary:

- drawing multiple type of shapes (lines, arrows, rectangles) by dragging
- changing zoom level of page for drawing more longer/wider graphs
- typing text

[asciiflow](http://asciiflow.com/) provides a mean for resizing shapes, which is not necessary for me. Also it is better to be able to draw other shapes like circle. An open source software is appropriated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the [asciiflow](https://asciiflow.com/#/) provided a tool which can be launched locally. See the [installation](https://github.com/lewish/asciiflow#installation) section of GitHub page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this C++ project: [schorsch1976/AsciiFlowQT: QT Based Ascii Chart editor](https://github.com/schorsch1976/AsciiFlowQT), it currently supports building against either QT or wxWidgets, so it is cross platform.

Comment: The idea is that you give it a review, so that readers know it could work without visiting the website

Comment: Yes, I have built it today with wx library. see this link https://github.com/schorsch1976/AsciiFlowQT/issues/4, it also has some screen shots.